# Optimum way to update sql data by the second

Tags: php, mysql, performance, cron, capacity

I have a between 100-150 of rows of data in my sql database being used in a PHP website/app.

Each item in the database rows represent a 'product offer'. Each offer has several basic properties, a validity status and an expiry date.

As each offer is listed on the webpage a clock will countdown to its given expiry date. If an offer has the validity status of 'Live' when its expiry date is reached, the status of the offer will need to update to 'expired'. As well as this some other PHP functions will be required to occur (these send transactional emails and update watching lists for users)

The coundown timer i'm using is able to fire a callback upon countdown to its given expiry date. This could trigger an AJAX command to update the offers validity status and do whatever else I require. However if I have 100 people viewing the offers page, that would trigger 100 events upon the callback, and if no-one is on my page the event wouln't trigger at all. So that's not a viable solution.

I considered CRON jobs but i understand these often run at a maximum of one minute, again this wouldn't be suitable as offers expire by the second.

How do sites like ebay update their listing information for thousands of rows of data per day on the second items reach their end time?

Are there any examples of best practice to minimise server load?

Comment: When you are entering an offer add its expiry time. When a user visits your website initiate the counter as expiry time- current time. So you have a counter and you not need to update table. When a user uses offer check if use time is less than expired time.

Comment: If I have 400 members, how would this solution email all 400 people the one time and do this event automatically when expiry time occurs?

Comment: So, now this is a second question as you never mentioned something like this in the question. For  that you must use cron or some alternative.

Comment: 100 AJAX calls leading to 100 `SELECTs` per second is not a problem.  1000/sec would possibly need an extra webserver, but not yet an extra MySQL server.  10K/sec may get into dicey territory.

Comment: Thanks Rick, Gone with a Cron job running every 20 seconds. Was unsure as how large my query could be running on such regular intervals. I'm querying roughly 40-50 rows of data per query and runs smooth as I need it to. During the 19 or so seconds that someone can view a listing inbetween expiry date and the cron job, a display message is shown through the website to manage any user confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The better option are doing this on two steps.

Delete the AJAX event. Do a check with ajax: For example, when timer expires (on ajax), they disable the purchase button, or another required task.

On web server, do two things: First, use a cron or similar to expire every minute. Second, on a "purchase" attempt (if your page is a store), check if the requested offer is already valid.

That's the better aproach you can use.